# How do I turn this initialization into modern js?

Tags: javascript, electron

In the [Electron](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest) page shows this brief example in how to initialize a new window

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')
const path = require('path')

function createWindow () {
  const win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
    }
  })

  win.loadFile('index.html')
}

app.whenReady().then(() => {
  createWindow()

  app.on('activate', () => {
    if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
      createWindow()
    }
  })
})

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit()
  }
})
```

I want to know how do I turn this into modern async/await javascript and not use the callback hell of `.then()`
This is what i tried

```
(async () => {
    const ready = await app.whenReady()

    if (ready) {
        createMainWindow()

        app.on('activate', () => {
            if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
                createMainWindow()
            }
        })

        app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
            if (process.platform !== 'win32') {
                app.quit()
            }
        })
    } else {
        console.error('App crashed')
    }

})()
```

but failed miserably, where am i wrong?
*btw im using babel for transpiling so theres no technical issues from that part*

Answer (score 0):

There's no `ready` variable in the first script, so you shouldn't have `if (ready)`.

Just use `await whenReady()` and write the rest of the code without checking the return value.

If you want to detect an error when using `await`, use `try/catch` around it. The `catch` block will be executed whenever the `.catch()` continuation of the promise would have been invoked. But you have no such continuation in the original code.

Comment: the first script is the reference from the webpage 
i just changed the part from below for modernizing the js but it doesnt work